# struts-jquery tags in pom.xml

Tags: jquery, spring, maven, struts2

I want to add jQuery to my application Struts2 but when I use the dependency in pom.xml it's give me this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project docgenview: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.atos.ma.si.delivery:docgenview:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:4.5 (test), org.apache.struts:struts2-jquery-plugin:jar:3.6.1 (compile), org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.3.14 (compile), org.apache.struts:struts2-sitemesh-plugin:jar:2.3.14 (compile), org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:jar:2.3.14 (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4 (provided), javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0 (provided), commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.1.1 (compile), commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2 (compile), uk.ltd.getahead:dwr:jar:1.1-beta-3 (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE (test), org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.9.Final (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.9.Final (compile), org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.9 (compile), com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.0.7 (compile), com.lowagie:itext-rtf:jar:2.1.4 (compile), org.apache.struts:struts-tiles:jar:1.3.10 (compile), displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2 (compile), cglib:cglib:jar:2.2 (compile), org.directwebremoting:dwr:jar:2.0.2 (compile), jstl:jstl:jar:1.2 (compile), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.struts:struts2-jquery-plugin:jar:3.6.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.struts:struts2-jquery-plugin:pom:3.6.1 from/to internal (http://archiva.karaz.org/repository/internal): Connection to 142.4.207.240:6060 refused: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect

(1) your networking is broken , check if you can access maven central repo

(2) your local repo is broken, goto [user home].m2\repository , then delete all folders inside, then re-build your project

Comment: it's give me an error 
 No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\PC-HOME\.m2\repository), internal (http://archiva.karaz.org/repository/internal)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] ! :/

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to see what happens.

or add `-X` parameter when you package it

Comment: it"s give this error 
Downloading: http://archiva.karaz.org/repository/internal/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/struts2-jquery-plugin/3.6.1/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.1.pom
[DEBUG] onThrowable
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information to http://142.4.207.240:6060/repository/internal/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/struts2-jquery-plugin/3.6.1/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.1.pom
 at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:95)
 at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)

Comment: Did you find which dependency ask for this ? Did you have special setting for repo ?